# Cannot get HttpClient working with PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying really hard to use HttpClient lib in my project.

I can't figure out what's going on...

I tried local URLs, examples online, even on Xamarin.Forms pages and nothing. It just doesn't work and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here.

This is code: (taken from here, btw: https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/HttpClient/HttpClientDemo/Earthquake/GeoNamesWebService.cs)

[image]

The second breakpoint is never hit.

This is my references section:

[image]

I tried manually inserting the System.Net.Http like I saw in some examples, but it also doesn't work:

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

To add more information. If I use my local server and set a breakpoint there, it is never hit as well. It looks like the request never "leaves" the application. And I think this could be related to not being able to add `System.Net.Http`. But I don't know... It's really stressing me out...

Waiting to resolve:

[image]

Fiddler:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
3675    200 HTTP    api.geonames.org    /earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=bertt  1,232   no-cache    application/json;charset=UTF-8  windowsformsapplication1.vshost:18544
```

TARGET:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you replace 'var earthquakesJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;' with 'var earthquakesJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();' ?

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos same thing, second BP is never hit. Please check my updated answer with the code.

Comment: Ok, I see your change, but why are you still trying to get the result with ".Result", instead of just await-ing?

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos no reason, just some crazy tests I'm running trying to figure it out. But even if I do await `return await earthquakesJson;` it still never reaches the second BP.

Comment: Just tested your code and it works here. Xamarin Studio, Xamarin.Forms PCL on a Mac. I think you should check your PCL profile.

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos my PCL profile is 259, please check the new image. Also, I'm pretty sure the problem is with my machine/project. I just can't figure out what it is! :(

Comment: This needs some troubleshooting, as Chris Clark suggested. I recommend testing if HttpClient results something from a simple url first. Pass it www.google.com or something and take it from there. Also, enclose it in a try/catch block. Maybe an exception is thrown, but is not being caught by VS for some reason (settings?).

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos gonna take a look at the exception settings, I indeed forgot about that. About simple URLs I've tried with no luck. I'll get back to you. And about Chris Clark suggestion I've done that and the URL is leaving (opposed to what I though) the app, it just never returns.

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos no exception is thrown. I had already tried wrapping the code with try/catch before. Fiddler says it's reaching the destination it's not returning though. Tried google.com again and same results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more troubleshooting at this point, because there are numerous things that could be going wrong.

1. Download Fiddler, and try typing the url in yourself to see if you are receiving a response.
2. Clean your solution, and rebuild.

Comment: I did that and fiddler says it's returning the data. I've cleaned and rebuilt several times since yesterday and again now... do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for referring to fiddler. It helped me figure out what was the issue. I still can't debug, but at least now I'm able to receive the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly reccomend checking out Flurl instead of HTTPClient.

Here's the nuget package [here] (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/)

and the link to the [documentation](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/)

It's very simple to get your results and parsing them, especially with Json:

```
T poco = await "http://api.foo.com".GetJsonAsync<T>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding in the nuget component HttpClient from microsoft. You require this to work with PCLs

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Comment: Yes, if you check my references section, the ...Primitives and ...Extensions come from that lib. Just System.Net.Http that doesn't show up.